# $\operatorname{trace}(B)>0$, and $C$ is a Hermitian positive definite, is $\operatorname{trace}(BC)\geq 0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, trace, positive-definite

Let $B$ is a Hermitian matrix such that $\operatorname{trace}(B)>0$ (but $B$ is "not" positive definite), and $C$ is a Hermitian positive definite matrix. Can we conclude $\operatorname{trace}(BC)\geq 0$? I tried two approaches, but neither worked.

1) We can write 
$$\operatorname{trace}(BC)=\operatorname{trace}(C^{1/2}BC^{1/2})$$
where $C^{1/2}$ is positive definite, and thus $C^{1/2}BC^{1/2}$ is congruent with $BC$. But congruence  just preserves the number of positive/negative/zero eigenvalues, and doesn't say anything about the magnitude, so apparently this doesn't say anything about the sign of $\operatorname{trace}(BC)$.

2) We can also write eigenvalue decomposition of $B$ and $C$:
$$B=\sum_i \beta_ib_ib_i^T \quad\text{and}\quad C=\sum_i \gamma_ic_ic_i^T$$
Hence,
$$\operatorname{trace}(BC)=\sum_i\sum_j\beta_i\gamma_j|b_i^Ta_j|^2$$
We know $\gamma_j>0$ (from positive-definiteness of $C$) and $|b_i^Ta_j|^2\geq 0$, but for $\beta_i$, we only know $\sum_i\beta_i>0$. So I don't know how we can conclude $\sum_i\sum_j\beta_i\gamma_j|b_i^Ta_j|^2\geq 0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not necessarily.  For instance, consider
$$
B = \pmatrix{2&0\\0&-1}, \quad C = \pmatrix{1&0\\0&3}
$$

Comment: You might be interested in the following fact: if $B$ is Hermitian, then we can only have
$
\operatorname{trace}(BC) \geq 0
$ for all positive (semi)definite $C$ if $B$ is itself positive semidefinite.

Comment: That is interesting fact, I didn't know about the "only" part of it.